# Is it wrong in XML to have element nodes as siblings of text nodes?

Tags: xml, nodes, markup

Is the following "allowed" or simply bad use of XML? I cannot find restrictions on this, but it feels a bit weird.

```
<example>
    You can choose from
    <option>this</option>
    <option>that</option>
    <option>something else</option>
    Choose wisely.
</example>
```

If it is wrong, what is a nice alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, mixing elements and text is completely normal in XML.

You may be more familiar with data-oriented uses of XML, but XML actually evolved from a basis in representing documents, where marking up text within other text is the norm.  Its predecessor, SGML, was like this, and HTML is still like this today.

In XML Schema (XSD), `mixed="true"` designates mixed text in a content model.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I am using an XML file that can be edited in the browser (using Javascript). I didn't feel the need for making a XSD. Is this still recommended?

Comment: An XSD communicates the structure and content of XML, and it allows automated verification against the constraints it expresses.  If neither of these capabilities are of value to you, you needn't feel obligated to make an XSD.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to reserve mixed content for one purpose only: to annotate (or "mark-up") sections of natural language text. So a good test to apply is, does the text still make sense if the markup is removed?

In your example, my only criticism would be that if you remove the markup, what's left isn't grammatical: it's missing a full-stop after the first sentence.

Comment: It is used for natural language text in my case. The real use is for making up a list of statutes, that contains articles, limbs and subs. This means that texts have to be formatted that are like the following:

Article 11:
1. The membership ends by:
   a. the passing of the member
   b. termination of membership by member
   c. termintation of membership by the association
2. Membership can be terminated at every moment, without a period of notice

The numbered items are limbs, the alphabetically ordered items are subs. Limb 1 contains some text, but also subs as well.

Comment: The formatting of my comment is lost, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above (with which I agree) I would add that it depends on the purpose of the XML document. If the purpose is to communicate business data between applications then validation of the entire document may be a requirement. Mixed content cannot be strictly validated using XML Schema, and is usually avoided in business-to-business communications unless it is for documentation purposes only.